# How to pull the new version of a site with git automatically without needing to store the git password on the server?

Tags: git, deployment

I have a server and I want to create a script that will pull the new version of the site and do some other stuff. But in order to pull you need the git password, which I don't want to store it on my server. What are the best practices in doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssh keys seem to be what you are looking for. GitHubs explanation:

> We strongly recommend using an SSH connection when interacting with GitHub. SSH keys are a way to identify trusted computers, without involving passwords.

Here is the full article on the topic:
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys